# Problems with date parsing

Tags: java, parsing

Good evening, please tell me how to solve the problem with date parsing.
The data is written in txt. file, when I read it and parse ( including the date of the object) throws an error with the date (((please help me fix it. I use only javaCore.

```
public class DemoRoom {

public static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path path = new Path();
    RoomRepository roomRepository = new RoomRepository();


    Hotel hotel1 = new Hotel(1L, "Ajax", "Holland", "Amsterdam", "Amsterdamskaja");
    Hotel hotel2 = new Hotel(2L, "Slask", "Poland", "Wroclaw", "Wroclawskaja");
    Hotel hotel3 = new Hotel(3L, "Dynamo", "Ukraine", "Kyiv", "Obolonskaja");


    String newDate1 = "07-Jun-2019";
    String newDate2 = "10-Nov-2020";
    String newDate3 = "31-Dec-2020";

    Room room1 = new Room(1L, 2, 200.0, false, false, dateFormat.parse(newDate1), hotel1);
    Room room2 = new Room(2L, 5, 1900.99, true, true, dateFormat.parse(newDate2), hotel2);
    Room room3 = new Room(3L, 1, 499.99, true, false, dateFormat.parse(newDate3), hotel3);

    
    roomRepository.addRoom(room1, path.getRoomDB());
```

**Parsing**
The date is under the fifth element.

```
    @Override
public Room pars(String str) throws Exception {
    if (str == null)
        throw new Exception("String does not exist!");
    String[] arr = str.split(",");
    Room room = new Room();
    room.setId(Long.parseLong(arr[0]));
    room.setNumberOfGuests(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
    room.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(arr[2]));
    room.setBreakfastIncluded(Boolean.parseBoolean(arr[3]));
    room.setPetsAllowed(Boolean.parseBoolean(arr[4]));
    room.setDateAvailableFrom(DemoRoom.dateFormat.parse(arr[5]));
    new HotelRepository().findHotelById((arr[6]));
    return room;
}
```

**Result**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mody.png)
[image]

Comment: Why are you not using SimpleDateFormat class as in 1st example?

Comment: @MironBalcerzak I tried it doesn't work either((( 
`room.setDateAvailableFrom(SimpleDateFormat.getInstance().parse(arr[5]));`

Comment: See my answer.. @MironBalcerzak is referring to why you call getInstance().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* framework. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and so on.

## `LocalDate`

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

Avoid exchanging date-time values textually using localized formats. When exchanging strings, use only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. For a date-only value, that format is YYYY-MM-DD. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2019-06-07" ) ;
```

If you must parse localized strings, let `DateTimeFormatter` do the work.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" ) ;
```

Specify the `Locale` to use in parsing the name of the month.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;  
f = f.withLocale( locale ) ;
```

Parse your incoming data.

```
String input = "07-Jun-2019" ; 
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Your `Room` class should carry a member field of type `LocalDate`.

```
Room x = new Room ( … , localDate , … ) ;
```

And parse your inputs well before passing to a constructor. You should always expect faulty inputs.

```
try{
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
    …
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    … 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know this ((((
I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the code shown below, you're getting calling a method that returns a new instance of SimpleDateFormat that uses the default constructor instead of the constructor defining the format you require ("dd-MMM-yyyy").

```
    dateFormat.getInstance().parse(newDate1);
```

Remove the "getInstance()" part, and you'll be golden.

[image: get instance documentation from simple date fromat]

Comment: But when I try remove the "getInstance()", I get an error. I can't call the parser without it.
what to do?(((

Comment: @NikZim You need to pass the instance of dateFormat that you create earlier in the code. You're calling the DateFormat's static method of getting a default instance, you need to call your instance of the DateFormat class because only your instance knows the style (..MMM..) which you set.

Comment: I made the dateFormat a static field. Passed it to the parser and still doesn't work.((((

`public static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");`
Method pars
`room.setDateAvailableFrom(DemoRoom.dateFormat.parse(arr[5]));`


 **Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "07-Jun-2019"
 at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:396)
 at Demo.DemoRoom.main(DemoRoom.java:32)**

Comment: Can you update the original post with your entire code for the dateformat stuff?

Comment: You still aren't showing the part where you call dateFormat. You're calling DateFormat.parse instead of dateFormat.parse....